# How to reopen a deployed contract in remix to be able to use withdraw button?

Tags: remix

I deployed a contract yesterday in Remix, this is my first time, so I'm not really familiar. My laptop slept, and when it reopened, I can't find the bot created in the contracts of Remix now?

How do I access the originally deployed contract, I can see it on etherscan, but to get back to the withdraw, and run buttons on Remix, have no idea, please help, as my funds cannot be withdrawn. Contract shows on etherscan, but don't know what to do now. Appreciated. Meta mask was connected when the bot was showing in web3 and I can see the contract deployment etc in meta mask, but stumped what to do next.

All I want to do is withdraw the contract, to test the bot worked the past 24 hours, and then I will redeploy with different amount.

Comment: In case this helps, contract on etherscan https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb95343413e459a0f97461812111254163ae53467855c0d73e0f1e7c5b8442fa3   Transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x190639ea4cd938d83fa0d95a1b5f44518253cea6b98ad0bbd3bc1e720ab94c33

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "at address" feature of the remix interface to load those contracts deployed using remix.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bPAEltRhrE&ab_channel=ArturChmaro) on how to do it.

Comment: Says there is no contracts deployed, but there was yesterday and meta mask is showing it, thanks for helping, appreciate this

Comment: I asked artur too and I thought that his video was to re-use the old code to make new contract, not to find the old, one, but will try this if its used to find the old one

Comment: Do I need to recreate the bot I made yesterday?

Comment: Well there is a high chance what you made on remix wasn't a bot. Solidity is limited to create a bot.

Comment: Its interesting. That feature is used to bring the contract interface. I guess it is not fully available. Not sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, I got scammed, and my ETH drained, the interface was not the real REMIX< but a ghost site, mimicking this and I'm gutted, but learned a very tough lesson!

Comment: Really wish these things can be shut down, how the heck can that happen!  Don't go near this site https://remixethereumcompiler.github.io/#optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.js it is basically tricking you to drain your wallet!

Comment: Oh my God! Sorry to hear

Comment: Its becoming really crazy now, with people scamming left right and centre, dunno how people avoid this these days, i've been 10 years in crypto and avoided so far, just let my guard down as was hoping to accumulate a little bit extra ETH, as I only have a small amount, before the fork :( Now I have very very very little lol... been trying to spread the word about these scumbags, so please feel free to share this warning and tell others to avoid the site. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtOrHj83hSQ&lc=UgxH_XKoShURYz2oKrN4AaABAg.9eQaVzfSo0d9eQcZsepDFA I've reported twice to YT video still up!

Comment: Anyone with the skillset to investigate this you tube channel and help to do anything to stop them, they are posting links that are fake but look real and I'm definitely not the only one, meta mask help desk told me the wallet address that the funds drained to, but they can't get it back! Really awful feeling. This is the scumbag thief https://etherscan.io/address/0x4084c181243d9e53b8c8f7113bf142e7f00e98da basically as soon as I connected, and funded, it forwarded the money to this address, probably already gone elsewhere 2 seconds after that.

Comment: The guy is not an idiot, he interacted with me throughout but as soon as I ran the contract, he vanished with my ETH. Lots of the accounts following him looked real, interactions real, checked a lot out, but obviously not enough, these people are skilled at stealing what they don't earn or deserve, not only that but false sense of security that he had a BAYC handle on telegram so you assume that must be well funded and its real... anyway, appreciate everyone on this exchange, you guys are all great and honest!

Comment: I will see what I can do.

Comment: @UkCryptogal do you have your contract address?

Comment: Sorry, for being late, just logged in and saw this @emrah, thanks a lot, contract add is 0xfEc7f2813b7a9DDC37bcF9892FF47fa9E982D241

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0xfec7f2813b7a9ddc37bcf9892ff47fa9e982d241 these are all the transactions, showing that it was funded, but then drained to 0

Comment: So it seems the scammer is still working and getting money just shifted 11 eth from the address I listed above out to another account, the trail continues.  https://etherscan.io/tx/0x390164d158b54caac751982c055c894271d4d9623e846f4288c3c95b82f53e66

Comment: I think I understood how they scam people. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/133570/how-is-this-scam-code-transferring-tokens-to-the-unspecified-wallet-within/133585#133585

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code of the contract,

1. copy the solidity code
2. paste in one of the new solidity file in the remix ide.
3. compile it.
4. select the correct contract, instead of deploy, paste the contract
   address beside the button "At Address", after you paste it click the
   "At address" button. (make sure your connected wallet is connecting to
   the correct network.)
5. The contract should be loaded.

Comment: Thank you, I did all that, and tried to withdraw, only to find, I've been scammed, and absolutely gutted! Thanks again for replying though much appreciated, left it to Meta Mask who say they will not recover my ETH,